# PHP Extract substring after five consecutive integers

Tags: php, regex

I have addresses in my old database in this format:

```
147 Boulevard Vauban80101 ABBEVILLE
80 rue Henri Dunant94480 ABLON SUR SEINE
3465 route Eguilles13090 AIX EN PROVENCE
```

where the last words which are in Capital letters are the name of city.
I need to extract the city name from the string. The best way I think will be to  extract substring after the occurence of five consecutive integers, but I'm not able to do it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I would start from the end and just stop when I get a number then trim the result...

Comment: Who is upvoting these zero-effort questions?  Please stop ruining SO.  All questions are meant to show research and effort to qualify for answers.

Comment: You question is unclear: we don't know if this is a string with newlines, or an array of single-line strings.  You have shown no attempt to solve nor research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only posted this because SO deserves clean, efficient, educational solutions.   (Downvoting this refined, wiki answer is pointless.) This is your most efficient solution:

`/ \K[A-Z ]+$/`

-`\K` restarts the fullstring match after the pattern's leading space.
- `[A-Z ]+` greedily matches one or more spaces or uppercase letters.
-`$` this anchor identifies the end of the string.

It looks for a space, then restarts the fullstring match, and matches all uppercase letters and spaces until the end of the string.

This is fastest because there are no capture groups.  Capture groups cause drag.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 preg_match("/.+[0-9]{5} ([A-Z ]+)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

[Example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/moi)

`$output_array[1]` would be the city.

You could also adapt it to pull out the post number also:

```
 preg_match("/.+([0-9]{5}) ([A-Z ]+)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

`$output_array[1]` would be the post number. `$output_array[2]` would be the city.

Comment: @wow that would fail on `147A Boulevard Vauban80101 ABBEVILLE`

Comment: Unrefined regex for unrefined data source @mickmackusa :D

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Works perfectly, merci. I have a similar problem where I have strings like `Latitude: 44.207 Longitude: 0.622679` and I have to extract the values of latitude & longitude. The number of decimals is not fixed. Can you please help me with that too? Sorry to ask code but I have zero knowledge of `preg_match` and it is urgent.

Comment: @Echoes I’m going to be _super_ annoying and just tell you that `{5}` can be exchanged for any number, or a top and bottom: `{4,7}` would be anything between 4 and 7. `.` by itself means ‘anything’, but `\.` would mean an actual dot. Try http://rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html and you will get there – good luck.

Comment: @Echoes Before you post another question on StackOverflow.  You MUST research, search, and attempt to self-solve.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards You were super helpful instead. Thanks for explaining so it easily & precisely. Not only I got the answer but also actually understood regex's concept properly for the first time:)

Comment: @mickmackusa I understand that and I'm aware of SO guidelines. Just that it was very urgent and I had zero knowledge about usage of regex usage. My bad, I will avoid it in future.

Comment: @mickmackusa Maybe speed isn’t important? It sounds like Echoes is doing an import, only to be run once. Maybe Echoes wants the other parts of the string for other reasons (as mentioned above). Maybe other names have been put in capital letters, and the 5 numbers are the only sure way of finding this out? Your answer may be more ‘refined’, more ‘optimal’, and less painful to your eyes, but that doesn’t mean that mine isn’t less useful to the problem being solved.

Comment: Sure. Your answer provides the desired result.  Maybe you don't know about some of the techniques in my pattern, maybe you do -- it doesn't matter as long as you are posting your best methods with explanations.  That's what I did.  I wouldn't ask you to delete your answer.  20 rep points is ample payment for your answer.  When future readers come to this page, they expect to be directed to the best, most refined method (s). My primary concern is that the OP received answers without posting a coding attempt -- SO is too often used as a free coding service and that's not cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
 ([A-Z ]+)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxz5SZ/2)**

Php code

```
$re = '/ ([A-Z ]+)$/m';
$str = '147 Boulevard Vauban80101 ABBEVILLE
80 rue Henri Dunant94480 ABLON SUR SEINE
3465 route Eguilles13090 AIX EN PROVENCE
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

**[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/G1VqVx)**

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, it does. You are seeing the first version that I already fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
$my_string = "147 Boulevard Vauban80101 ABBEVILLE";
        if (preg_match('/(?<!\d)[0-9]\d{4}(?!\d)/is', $my_string, $matches))
            echo explode($matches[0],$my_string)[1];
```

this should work

Comment: Why are you limiting postal code to `[4-9]\d{4}`? The case insensitive flag is useless here. Why using `preg_match` **and** `explode`?

Comment: coz it need to count only 5 consicutive numbers. and that expression only returns the number so i need to explode with the number.

Comment: But it doesn't match postal code like `12300` or `25700`